# invalid-request on token request OAuth 2.0 for Devices with j2me

Tags: google-oauth

When i request a token in this example [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API) ,the response is a bad request,But i can get the device code and the connection is ok.
the url to get token is

Request: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&code=4/ELY3wywbZX8SQBRdqqYNIVAV3dCF&grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0

the method is post

i use HttpsConnection

any ideas

Comment: Make sure you send the parameters in the POST body, and not as query parameters.

Comment: This is happening for me too using a go command line application.